# Proton spin precession and alignment to magnetic field in NMR

Tags: magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, precession, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

Precession due to magnetic field occurs when the magnetic moment of a small coil is proportional to its angular momentum ($\vec{m}=g\vec{L}$). This is due to Euler momentum equation, which for such a system reads: $$\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}=\vec{M}=\vec{m}\times \vec{B}=g\vec{L}\times\vec{B}$$and has the shape of a precession equation. In NMR theory we are told that a single proton can both precess around a magnetic field and align to it. This happens because of its spin, so in principle even in absence of orbital angular momentum. First of all: to justify the precession, do we need to generalize Euler equation and write that $d\vec{J}/dt=\vec{M}$ (where $\vec{J}=\vec{L}+\hbar\vec{S})$? Does this always hold? Secondly, what causes alignment? Is alignment just a statistical prediction? Does it always hold?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the full angular momentum of the system considered, here $\vec{J}=\vec{L}+\vec{S}$ (note usually $\vec{S}$ is considered the spin, i.e. including the $\hbar$). This certainly holds for simple systems like this one, in more complex systems the specific type of spin-orbit coupling may need to be considered.

Alignment of protons in a magnetic field is caused by the interaction of the field with the proton's magnetic moment. The spin, and hence the moment, being parallel, or anti-parallel to the magnetic field vector result in different energy levels, therefore the proton's spin will show preference for the orientation with lower energy. At temperature $T=0$ all spins will settle in this orientation. At higher temperatures, thermal energy will cause a lot of the spins (up to 50%, or balanced, at very high temperatures) to switch to the non-preferred orientation; in this sense we're talking about a statistical phenomenon. In fact, at room temperature in easily achievable magnetic fields the relative imbalance for protons is only $10^{-10}$ .. $10^{-8}$, explaining why NMR signals are so small at room temperature.

The spin pointing up or down is terminology that neglects half of the picture. It only represents the z component of the spin (magnetic field assumed in z direction). The operators of the components of angular momentum do not commute, that means that with determined (certain) z component, the values of the x and y components are completely uncertain. In particular they are not zero, so, in a semi-classical picture, the spin never points just up or down. Continuing this picture, the residual misalignment results in a force on the spin causing precession. This precession is unsynchronised over the ensemble of spins, but can be synchronised by external RF pulses with the right frequency; the synchronisation lasts a while so that an echo can be detected. This is what we call NMR. A proper (more rigorous), but much less intuitive description of this can be given in terms of [Bloch vectors on a Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere).